# Best approach of Socket.io in Vue applications

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, vuex, real-time

This is my first post in Stackoverflow!

I'm wondering what is the best way to integrate socket.io into vue applications. Currently I am developing a real-time website and socket.io is my best choice because it's free :D

My plan is connecting socket.io into vuex and I don't know how to handle the changes in the data like Added, Removed or Modified.

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/@yusufborucu/vue-js-ve-socket-io-ile-basit-chat-uygulamas%C4%B1-yap%C4%B1m%C4%B1-c7b10f46ef3b

Answer (score 0):

You could have a start action in your vuex, and in that action you could listen the events.

Eg.

```
//...vuex module

// onChange is a normal function that is not inside: actions or mutations, but is declared in the samefile for ease of use
const onChange = ({commit}) => (...eventParams)=>{
  commit("...", changes)
}

// Inside actions
async start({commit}){
  socket.on(event, onChange({commit}))
  //...you could repeat the pattern for any mutation
}
```